# Binding provider that support writing to non observables

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I'm developing a convention library for KO

https://github.com/AndersMalmgren/Knockout.BindingConventions

Its using its own data-attribute and binding provider.
The built in one can one way bind to non observables for bindingHandlers updating the model with the `ko.expressionRewriting.writeValueToProperty` function (Its not exported). For example the `value` binding

Problem is I haven't been able to figure out how the built in binding provider enables this because I get lost in all the string eval code.

I could fix it with a computed, but I would rather do it like the built in one. Here is a fiddle proving that the built in version is working to write to non observables without computed

http://jsfiddle.net/xffPk/1/

So how do I enable writing to non observables to bindingHandlers that utilizes writeValueToProperty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it like this

```
var applyMemberWriter = function(bindings, bindingName, accessor, memberName, context) {
    if(!ko.isObservable(accessor)) {
        bindings._ko_property_writers = bindings._ko_property_writers || {};

        bindings._ko_property_writers[bindingName] = function(value) {
            context[memberName] = value;
        };
    }
};
```

This needs to be called to apply two way binding on none observables, full source
https://github.com/AndersMalmgren/Knockout.BindingConventions/commit/7d8e7cdf0ddced5b39f10c1b374bcd5254cc0a58

Above is for KO 2.x

For KO 3.x

https://github.com/AndersMalmgren/Knockout.BindingConventions/commit/78983119c1e5fb70c637e4ffc1b692d2b4c74dc7